# zend router optimization

Tags: zend-framework, routes

How can I optimize all of these routes into one. As we do in .htaccess file.

```
routes.addemails.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.addemails.route = "campaign/email/add"
routes.addemails.defaults.module = campaignManagement
routes.addemails.defaults.controller = Email
routes.addemails.defaults.action = add


routes.updateEmail.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.updateEmail.route = "campaign/email/edit/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.updateEmail.defaults.module = campaignManagement
routes.updateEmail.defaults.controller = Email
routes.updateEmail.defaults.action = edit
routes.updateEmail.map.key = 1

routes.delEmail.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.delEmail.route = "campaign/email/delete/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.delEmail.defaults.module = campaignManagement
routes.delEmail.defaults.controller = Email
routes.delEmail.defaults.action = delete
routes.delEmail.map.id = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not set up a route using a config file, but at a glance try:

```
routes.emails.route = "campaign/email/(add|edit|delete)/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)?"
routes.emails.map.action = 1
routes.emails.map.id = 2
```

I am assuming that the map.* are the variables in the url (so action is the first bit of regex, with id being the second bit of regex. Correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: you are right :). I was trying routes.emails.defaults.action=1 :)